# Multiplication of the input

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

For simplification purposes. I sometimes use this kind of declarations in Python2 if the number of inputs is known.

```
a, b, c = raw_input(), raw_input(), raw_input()
```

The created tuples handle the rest of the work. One day, I thought of trying this below.

```
a, b, c = [raw_input] * 3
```

It is not working as one would expect, or to put it better, it is not working like the one above. Well the reason is somewhat obvious. But is there another way exists to achieve this behavior ?

Comment: Do this: `a, b, c = [raw_input() for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: Clever, to create the list before evaluation. I wonder if there exists a even shorter answer.

Comment: Actually yes there is shorter: `a, b, c = map(raw_input, range(3))` (for Python 2 only). But this prints some garbage now.

Comment: You need to add paranthesis after that raw_input.

Comment: @Rockybilly nope, map actually takes a function as  an argument and applies it to the inputs [0,1,2] .  as such raw_input does not need parentheses.

Comment: Yes, I just realized(remembered actually) :D Thanks.

Comment: also, if you want to get rid of 0,1,2 print with each raw_input, you can use `a, b, c = map(raw_input, ['']*3)`

Comment: Or let's take the inputs with some eyecandy `a, b, c = map(raw_input, ["-> "]*3)`  :D

Answer (score 2):

```
a, b, c = [raw_input("Feed me! ") for _ in range(3)]
print a, b, c
```

You can't use the *3 on a one_item list; this will give you three copies of one input.  Here's the correct output from the above code:

```
Feed me! 6
Feed me! hello, Jack!
Feed me! False
6 hello, Jack! False
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well I already gave my opinion in question comments. Take my +1 sir.

Comment: This particular trick is also quite useful when generating random numbers: `[random.randrange(100) for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: @Rockabilly: I was in another window editing my answer.  The best I could do was to up-vote your comment.  Most of all, I'm happy to see we both used the underscore; it's a good thing to pass along.